# Spark REPL doesn't run due to an error

Tags: apache-spark

I got pre-built Spark 1.4.1 and I'm running HDP 2.6. when I run spark-shell it gives me an error message as follows. Is this because I'm missing a jar file ?

```
 ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AppClient.scala:160)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor.aroundReceive(AppClient.scala:61)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
```

what the problem is for?

I got another version of scala download and now I get a diferent error when running `scala-shell`. Here is the error.

```
 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@headnodehost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: headnodehost
15/07/23 15:25:59 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/07/23 15:25:59 WARN cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.164.136:4040
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/07/23 15:25:59 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/07/23 15:25:59 ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AppClient.scala:160)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
```

Comment: What is the command line you are using? Just `bin/spark-shell`?

Comment: yes exactly, do I need more arguments?

Comment: No. Which pre-built version are you using? I see you asked a bunch of other questions with other error messages. I think you're not using the right pre-built release.

Comment: that is the Spark 1.4.1 without HAdoop and I already have Hortonwork hadoop cluster installed (version 2.6.0)

Comment: Yeah, that's the wrong build. You need the pre-built release that matches your Hadoop version: 2.6 in this case. That will hopefully solve all your problems.

Comment: how can I find out the right version for my hadoop cluster? I can't anything in the download page.

Comment: HDP 2.6 is Hadoop 2.6 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and your other recent questions, the problem is that you've downloaded the *"pre-build with user provided Hadoop"* version of Apache Spark. Instead you should download the build for the Hadoop version that you have: 2.6 in this case.

The download link for Apache Spark 1.4.1 built for Hadoop 2.6 is http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz

Comment: I did the compatible version but I'm getting a different error message. Could you have a look at my updated post?

Comment: That's why your cluster doesn't seem to be running. Did you stop the old running cluster (master/slaves) and run the new one you've installed?